# How to create PBR materials from images?

Tags: texturing, pbr

I would like to know how you can create a PBR material from an image like this
using Photoshop or GIMP- I did see Blender Guru's tutorial, but I'm not able to work it out for this one. A bump  map, displacement and reflection map will do.

[image]

Comment: I think if you convert the image to Greyscale (Only B&W) and increase the contrast (Using "Levels") and then you can invert that result for the other map. *The Principled Shader is the more current.

Comment: TY... happy Blendering

Comment: There is an amazing program called Materialize which turns images into a PBR map where you get, Metallic, Albedo, AO, Edge Map and also Height map.

Comment: @MrFacysus thank you for that, I was looking for an open source alternative to CrazyBumps for a long time.